# Creating the error correction codewords for a QR code with Generator Polynomial

Tags: qr-code, error-correction, reed-solomon

i am trying to create Generator polynomial for 7 error correction code words. i don't understand how coefficients calculate. The QR code specification says to use byte-wise modulo 100011101 arithmetic (where 100011101 is a binary number that is equivalent to 285 in decimal). This means that when a **number** is 256 or larger, it should be XORed with 285.

In other words:
2^8 = 256 **xor** 285 = 29 ok. But how can i calculate **5334**?

5334 xor 285 = 5579 still bigger than 256.

the answer is 122. i don't understand how we found 122 ? thank you so much.

Comment: 5334 is a specific number. Our generator polynomial for 7 error correction code words:

x^7 +127x^6 + 5334x^5 + ... so on. XORed with 285: 


x^7 +127x^6 + 122x^5 + ...

Answer (score 0):

Think about numbers as about polynomials from F2[X]. It means that number one can be represented by 1, number 2 is represented by x, number 3 is represented by x + 1.

Number 5334 is represented by p_5334 = x^12+x^10+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^2+x^1

Number 285 is represented by p_285 = x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1

You need to get the polynomial p_5334 mod p_285.